# Issue of overriding Desktop styles in iphone

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, media-queries

I have created an ASP.NET MVC Application which run on Iphone,Ipad and desktop. When i try to run the application in iphone my desktop style is overriding the iphone styles. How can avoid this? I have put my desktop styles on the top pf the page like below.

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/desktop.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css")" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="@Url.Content("~/Content/mhome-style.css")" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bib.css")" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jplayer.blue.monday.css")" />

    @* Styles for Iphone *@
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/iphone_portrait.css")" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px)" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/iphone_landscape.css")" />
    @* Styles for Ipad *@
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ipad_portrait.css")" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) " href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ipad_landscape.css")" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too knowledgable about asp.net, but it looks like the problem could be fixed by putting a min-width media query on the desktop stye-sheets, so that they don't get loaded on smaller devices.

Comment: After setting min width to desktop styles my issue is resolved.